Analyzing Gap Years in SQL
I have a table (myt) in SQL that looks like this:
CREATE TABLE myt (
    Name VARCHAR(50),
    Date_1 DATE,
    Date_2 DATE,
    Year_1 INT,
    Month_1 INT,
    Day_1 INT,
    Year_2 INT,
    Month_2 INT,
    Day_2 INT
);


INSERT INTO myt (ID, Name, Date_1, Date_2, Year_1, Month_1, Day_1, Year_2, Month_2, Day_2) VALUES
( 'p1', '2010-01-01', '2010-05-01', 2010, 1, 1, 2010, 5, 1),
( 'p2', '2010-01-01', '2013-09-09', 2010, 1, 1, 2013, 9, 9);


  Name     Date_1     Date_2 Year_1 Month_1 Day_1 Year_2 Month_2 Day_2
 p1 2010-01-01 2010-05-01   2010       1     1   2010       5     1
 p2 2010-01-01 2013-09-09   2010       1     1   2013       9     9

Task:

For each row, I want to find out how many feb-01 appear between date_1 and date_2.

For example:

P1: (date_1 = 2010-01-01, date_ 2= 2010-05-01 ) the answer is 1 (feb1 2010)

P2: (date_1 = 2010-01-01, date_2= 2013-09-09) the answer is 4 (feb1 2010 , feb1 2011, feb1 2012, feb1 2013)


I tried looking if there were specific SQL functions for this and didn't find any, so I tried to do this using a standardized approach:
SELECT *, 
       (year_2 - year_1 + 
       (CASE WHEN month_1 < 2 OR (month_1 = 2 AND day_1 <= 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - 
       (CASE WHEN month_2 < 2 OR (month_2 = 2 AND day_2 < 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) as feb1_count
FROM myt;

The results seem to look correct for these test cases:
Name     Date_1     Date_2 Year_1 Month_1 Day_1 Year_2 Month_2 Day_2 feb1_count
   P1 2010-01-01 2010-05-01   2010       1     1   2010       5     1          1
   P2 2010-01-01 2013-09-09   2010       1     1   2013       9     9          4

Is this the correct way to analyze this problem?

As long as the date you're counting isn't 29th February, your solution would work.
There's a minute asymmetry in the calculation though, with the terms:
(month_1 = 2 AND day_1 <= 1)
(month_2 = 2 AND day_2 < 1)

I think you can make the code symmetric (or maybe anti-symmetric) by adapting it to read:
SELECT *, 
       (year_2 - year_1 - 1 + 
       (CASE WHEN month_1 < 2 OR (month_1 = 2 AND day_1 <= 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 
       (CASE WHEN month_2 > 2 OR (month_2 = 2 AND day_2 >= 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) as feb1_count
FROM myt;

As long as date_1 <= date_2, that should work, even for edge cases:



Date 1
Date 2
Y2-Y1-1
Case 1
Case 2
Answer
Status




2010-02-01
2010-02-01
-1
1
1
1
✓


2010-01-31
2010-02-02
-1
1
1
1
✓


2010-01-30
2010-01-31
-1
1
0
0
✓


2010-02-02
2010-02-02
-1
0
1
0
✓


2010-02-02
2011-01-31
0
0
0
0
✓


2010-02-02
2011-02-01
0
0
1
1
✓


2010-01-01
2013-09-09
2
1
1
4
✓




A general approach here uses a trick involving a calendar table.  Define a table containing February 1st for every year you need to cover.  Then left join your current table to this calendar table and aggregate by the ID.
-- replace the CTE below with an actual table for better performance

WITH dates AS (
    SELECT '2010-02-01' AS dt UNION ALL
    SELECT '2011-02-01' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2012-02-01' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2013-02-01' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2014-02-01' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2015-02-01'
)

SELECT t1.Name, t1.Date_1, t1.Date_2, t1.Year_1, t1.Month_1, t1.Day_1,
       t1.Year_2, t1.Month_2, t1.Day_2, COUNT(t2.dt) AS feb1_count
FROM myt t1
LEFT JOIN dates t2
    ON t2.dt BETWEEN t1.Date_1 AND t1.Date_2
GROUP BY t1.Name, t1.Date_1, t1.Date_2, t1.Year_1, t1.Month_1, t1.Day_1,
         t1.Year_2, t1.Month_2, t1.Day_2;


The downside of this approach is the hassle of creating the list of candidate dates — you need a table with one entry for the anniversary date in each year between YEAR(MIN(date1)) and YEAR(MAX(date2)).  The upside is that it can handle 29th February too, and could also easily handle "fixed holidays each year: 1st January, 4th July, 25th December", assuming you generate those dates for each year in the range.
